# Cache Memory and fglrx driver slows computer

Tags: virtualbox, fglrx, cache

When ever my Cache memory gets extremely high, my entire computer slows down. Windows slow to load, and there's lagging on the mouse-overs for everything. The only way I can restore everything is by rebooting. This happens particularly whenever I view a youtube or any video in fullscreen. The Cache memory goes up, and the computer slows. It has just happened again after making a virtual box vdi file. After creating a blank vdi file, the computer is really slow.

I don't think virtual machine usage has anything to do with it, since it happens even when I haven't loaded any virtual machines.

It happens mostly when I watch a video in full screen. Next time it happens, I'll try to see what more information I can find in the system monitor.

I use the fglrx driver for my ATI Radeon 5000 series graphics card, but I'm unsure if this is a driver issue. This occurred in Ubuntu 10.04, so I installed Ubuntu 11.10 (removing 10.04) thinking it would solve the problem, but it hasn't.

Comment: Did you assing too much RAM to the virtual machine? Check the configuration of the virtual machint. Also you can see what programs use what ressources using top command. If you use virtual machines I suggest enabling virtualization in BIOS and installing at least 4 GB of RAM (I have 16 GB). Cache _IS_ always slow. The fglrx driver is on my opinion NOT related to your issue, only your RAM usage. Maybe you have more information on what you are doing. Best is, if Ubuntu does not use any swap memory!!

Comment: you say you updated to 11.10 and you use fglrx drivers. did you remove those before updating?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm pretty sure I've identified the problem.

It might relate to this [bug (720446)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/720446) and this [bug (779717)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-multiload/+bug/779717)

Has to do with memory leakage by unity, compiz and the system load indicators.